# Angular Unit Testing Code Coverage for Void: ()=>

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a simple ngOnInit() function in my component.ts file with a const variable of type void. By any chance anyone know how to cover that line of code and go inside that void method?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common'

export type SessionHandler = ()=> void;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'test';

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any){}

  ngOnInit() {
   const sess: SessionHandler = (): void =>{
     console.log('Meoww');
   }
   this.testService.func(sess);
  }
  }
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] of component and test, **as text**, in the question.

Comment: When i tried to call ngOnInit() method. It's not going inside that void() function as mentioned in the above image

Comment: Why would it? That's just a locally defined function, nothing calls it (then it goes out of scope and nothing *can*).

Comment: can you let me know how to make a call to that and get that covered?

Comment: Delete it - as written, it's pointless. You define a function that's never used.

Comment: What if it's getting called inside ngOnInit(). Then also it's not getting covered.

Comment: In your updated version it's **not** called, it's passed to the testService to (presumably) be called later. It's unclear what testService is in real life, it's not injected into the constructor, or in the test. Presumably there'd be a test double of it, in which case you'd check that the test double's method is called with a function. You'd also have access to the function via the method's calls list, so then you could invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover that void function by calling it in the onInit() itself and then writing your expectations for the onInit() method call. IMO, you should have this void function outside of onInit() and you can call it inside onInit for easier testing.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'test';

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any){}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.sess();
  }
  sess: SessionHandler = (): void => {
     console.log('Meoww');
  }
}
```